# Accidentally used dd command

Tags: dd

I have been following a tutorial online to teach myself some basic command line stuff and accidentally I used the `dd` command (which I haven't gotten to and don't understand), but it seems to have done something to my computer.

The image below shows exactly what I typed (`dd`, followed by hitting enter, another `d`, a few more enters, a few more enters, before a Ctrl+C to stop execution as I had learned).
[image]

Could I ask what this has done, if it is potentially harmful, and if it is, how I would remediate it?

Comment: What makes you think anything was done to your computer? You'd see the same result if you typed `cat`.

Comment: @Barmar Because someone's who's only familiar with `dd` as a tool to "convert and copy files" (which is its intended purpose) would assume that what it had done was convert and/or copy files...which could easily cause damage?

Comment: Sorry @Barmar I am very new and I had heard that you can harm your computer with wrong inputs to the command line.

Comment: Unless you're running as root, you should rarely be able to harm the computer. The worst you can do is delete or corrupt your personal files.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

`dd` with no arguments reads from its standard input and writes to its standard output; you haven’t done anything to your computer.

Answer (score 6):

You can think of `dd` as a versatile copy command.

The [man page](https://manpages.org/dd) for it (`man dd`) describes it this way:

> Copy a file, converting and formatting according to the operands.

It is often used to copy a whole disk or parts of a disk to a file or another disk and thus is often called *dangerous*, because if you mix up input and output you might overwrite the wrong disk and destroy your files.

When no parameters are given, `dd` defaults to simply copying the contents of its standard input to its standard output.

In your case, typing `dd` without any arguments in a console and pressing Enter, that means that it copies your keyboard input to the console output and does nothing more. So you didn't do any harm to your computer.